# SQL query for finding domain of an email address

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table of `emails` and a table of `domains`. How can I `UPDATE` the email column to SET the `domain_id` which is a `foreign_key` to the table domains.

**Domains**

```
domain_id    domain
1            google.co.uk
2            google.com
3            domain.com
4            domain.gov.au
```

**Emails**

```
email_id     email                         domain_id
1            john@admin.google.co.uk
2            john@google.com
3            john@ne.domain.gov.au
4           john@domain.com
```

*The tricky part is that emails can be based on the top-level domain or subdomain.*

Comment: *"UPDATE the email column to SET the domain_id"*: that is confusing. You want to update both columns?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
update emails e join
       domains d
       on e.email like concat('%', d.domain)
    set e.domain_id = d.id;
```

Note:  This is not efficient, because it won't use an index.  But for a one-time effort, it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it using `LIKE` operator

```
select E.email_id, E.email, D.domain_id
from Domains D 
Inner Join Emails E 
        ON E.email like concat('%',D.domain,'%')
```

Above query can be converted to `Update` statement